# Android Studio Button not Responding (OnClick)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have tried various tutorials and no matter what , the button just never responds.

Here is the Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button handbtn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    handbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnHandSigns);

    handbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent loadsigns = new Intent(MainActivity.this, hand_signs.class);
            startActivity(loadsigns);
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Inside the onClick add `Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "check", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`. Click the button. Does it show a toast message?

Comment: Your code should be working perfectly fine. Please try what Kurlicue wrote and give us the result. Also, is the button the only view in you activity? If it isn't, check if any other (invisible) view might covers your button. You could also try a clean build, in Android Studio via Build>Clean Build and then try it again.

Answer (score 0):

The above code is confirmed working on my machine.

I would add this as a comment but I don't have enough reputation.

You might want to check the following things exist:

- R.id.btnHandSigns exist, in activity_main.xml you have something like

  `<Button
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:id="@+id/btnHandSigns" />`
- hand_signs.java and activity_hand_signs.xml

If they both exist consider pasting the logcat from when you click the button.

Answer (score 0):

I can not see anything wrong in your code you posted, but i can see you missed a "close brace" :)
Try to make a Toast to check if all thing in onClick method is work properly.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding in `onCreate()` method:

```
handbtn.setOnClickListener(this);
```